# What is the best way to handle C# events inside a container class?

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-core, event-handling

I have written a C# class called `DownloadTask` that fires an event when a file finishes downloading. I want to have multiple `DownloadTask` classes all kept in a container class, `DownloadTaskManager`. `DownloadTaskManager` contains a `List<DownloadTask> tasks` object. I use methods such as `Add()`, `Remove()`, `ClearAllTasks()`, etc. to interact with that list. My question is, if I wanted my container class, `DownloadTaskManager`, to also keep track of each `DownloadTask`'s event, what is the best way to do so?

Comment: `downloadTask.EventName += eventHandler`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "keep track of each Download Task event" you mean attaching listeners to them:

- You can add the event to the task before adding it, but I think this is not what you want
- You can modify the signature of the `Add` method exposed from the `DownloadTaskManager` (if you don't have one, you should create it) to something like `Add(string id, DownloadTask task)`, then you can create a method like `RegisterEvent(string id, Action onDownloaded)` to add a specific event handlers to specific tasks

You have to provide to the outside of the `DownloadTaskManager` class a way to identifying specific tasks, so you can map them internally.

Comment: Your second point is what I am looking for the most. Thank you.